# Where does DSPAM fit into the chain

Tags: linux, postfix, dspam

Is there any postfix guru here who knows that after a mail gets into postfix what's the order it gets forwarded between the internal filters and components?

As I figured:

1, Postscreen

2, Recipient checks

```
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain
        permit_mynetworks
        check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override
        reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        check_policy_service inet:1.2.3.4:4000
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
```

3, Message passed on to dspam

```
virtual_transport = dspam:unix:/var/run/dspam/dspam.sock
```

4, Dspam does additional checks then forwards the mail to the next component.

Is this about right?

Comment: There may possibly be some other small steps, but yes, that seems about right (don't think I'm a guru though :/ )

Comment: @NickW I think you just became one, congrats

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see it moving through the server, hopefully I haven't omitted anything too egregious.

Postscreen would normally be the first point of contact, but usually only for external servers submitting on port 25.

When `postscreen` validates the connection it then passes it on to `smtpd` which will perform checks which are designed to complete before the connection is closed with the remote server. Assuming those checks went fine, `smtpd` will pass the connection on to the `cleanup` daemon/server, and into the `incoming` queue.

Then, if the `active` queue is not full, the mail will be passed from the `incoming` queue to the `active` queue, and then to the `qmgr` who will then send it to the DSPAM sock, and since postfix uses the `virtual_transport` route, it considers it delivered if the DSPAM socket accepts it.

DSPAM will then check the mail, and if it passes, forward it to dovecot or another LDA.

Comment: And just one more question, where does ClamAV fit in? I didn't notice I have this in my setup too: smtpd_milters = unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl

Comment: That would actually be in the first section, along with the other checks that are performed before the remote connection with the server is closed.. smtpd_milters are also called before queue milters.